# Error: Could not find or load main class Mac Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

So I'm using Eclipse on a Mac running Mavericks and I changed the default save location to another folder, but every time I try to build a new project this error keeps popping up... error: Could not find or load main class. Here is my code for my two classes if this helps.

```
//Employee.java
package Exercise314;
public class Employee 
{
String firstName;
String lastName;
double monthlySalary;

public Employee (String fName, String lName, double mSalary)
{
    firstName = fName;
    lastName = lName;
    monthlySalary = mSalary;
}
public void setFirstName (String fName)
{
    firstName = fName;
}
public void setLastName (String lName)
{
    lastName = lName;
}
public void setMonthlySalary (double mSalary)
{
    if(mSalary > -1)
        monthlySalary = mSalary;
}
public String getFirstName ()
{
    return firstName;
}
public String getLastName ()
{
    return lastName;
}
public double getMonthlySalary ()
{
    return monthlySalary;
}
}
//EmployeeTest.java
package Exercise314;
public class EmployeeTest 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    Employee employee1 = new Employee(
            "Joe", "Smith", 150000 );
    Employee employee2 = new Employee(
            "Jane", "Doe", 95000 );
    System.out.printf("First name is: %s\n",
            employee1.getFirstName() );
    System.out.printf("Last name is: %s\n",
            employee1.getLastName() );
    System.out.printf("Salary is: %f\n\n",
            employee1.getMonthlySalary() );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Being a Mac user and having both Eclipse Luna and STS installed I would recommend that you restart Eclipse. If that doesn't work, restart your Mac. That is what I do when I encounter the same error.

Comment: Nope that didn't work. I just noticed though that I don't have a bin.

Comment: I switched workspaces then imported my project, and it worked perfectly. Who would've thunk it.

Comment: If that helped, great. Can I get a +1 or get the answer? Thanks!

Comment: I can't give you a +1 cause my rep stinks lol, but I'll give you the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Looks like in Eclipse Luna the workspace architecture has changed and it requires cleaning the existing build and re-building again. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

*Here is what that worked for me :*

1) Go to Run Configuration.
2) Delete the class which you want to run (right click -> delete).
3) Run your java class again from eclipse.